# UIView Function Bug

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a UIView function which when called will return a view with 2 buttons, a TextView in some stackViews. I am having trouble and at the moment all it is returning is an empty rectangle(it's not showing any of the info inside). What am I doing wrong?

```
func returnView(text1: String, text2: String) -> UIView {

let customView = UIView()
let firstButton = UIButton()
let secondButton = UIButton()
let textView = UITextView()

customView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 90)
customView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.82, green:0.83, blue:0.85, alpha:1.0)

firstButton.setTitle(text1, for: .normal)
firstButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.48, blue:1.00, alpha:1.0), for: .normal)
firstButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: UIFont.Weight.medium)

secondButton.setTitle("apple", for: .normal)
secondButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.48, blue:1.00, alpha:1.0), for: .normal)
secondButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: UIFont.Weight.medium)

textView.text = text2

let stack1 = UIStackView()
stack1.axis = .horizontal
stack1.alignment = .fill 
stack1.distribution = .fillEqually 

stack1.addArrangedSubview(firstButton)
stack1.addArrangedSubview(secondButton)

let stack2 = UIStackView()
stack2.axis = .horizontal
stack2.alignment = .fill 
stack2.distribution = .fillEqually

stack2.addArrangedSubview(textView)

let fullStack = UIStackView()
fullStack.axis = .vertical
fullStack.alignment = .fill
fullStack.distribution = .fillEqually
fullStack.addArrangedSubview(stack1)
fullStack.addArrangedSubview(stack2)

customView.addSubview(fullStack)

stack1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
stack2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
fullStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([fullStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customView.topAnchor), fullStack.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customView.leftAnchor), fullStack.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customView.rightAnchor), fullStack.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customView.heightAnchor), (fullStack.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customView.centerXAnchor))])

return customView
}
```

**EDIT** I am calling it from this function:

```
func renderAttachment() {

    let view = returnView(text1: "test1", text2: "test2")

    // Render Image
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: view.frame.size)
    let image = renderer.image {
        view.layer.render(in: $0.cgContext)
    }

    // Create Attachment
    let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
    attachment.image = image
    attachment.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: image.size)

    // Current Attributed String
    let atStr = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: textview.attributedText)

    // Insert Attachment
    let attachmentAtStr = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
    if let selectedRange = textview.selectedTextRange {
        let cursorIndex = textview.offset(from: textview.beginningOfDocument, to: selectedRange.start)
        atStr.insert(attachmentAtStr, at: cursorIndex)
        atStr.addAttributes(self.textview.typingAttributes, range: NSRange(location: cursorIndex, length: 1))
    } else {
        atStr.append(attachmentAtStr)
    }
    textview.attributedText = atStr
    print(atStr)
}
```

This is how it shows in my textView(just an empty box!) [image]

Comment: I added your function to a fresh project and added `view.addSubview(returnView(text1: "Hello World!", text2: "Foo Bar Baz"))` to `viewDidLoad()` and your view did show up with content.  Note that your frame places the view in the upper left corner of the screen behind the title bar and notch of an iPhone X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to add a view using your function and it worked perfectly fine. Please see below screenshot.

[image]

add below line of code after the self.returnView(text1: "Test1", text2: "Test2") function call.

```
view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Added an edit with more info, tell me what you think?

Answer (score 1):

You are rendering a view that hasn't been added to a view hierarchy, so you need to trigger layout by calling `view.layoutIfNeeded()`:

```
let view = returnView(text1: "test1", text2: "test2")
view.layoutIfNeeded()

// Render Image
let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: view.frame.size)
let image = renderer.image {
    view.layer.render(in: $0.cgContext)
}
```